# Disable Spring Cloud Stream Rabbit for tests

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I use:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I need to disable Rabbit for testing the application. I tried this:

```
spring:
    cloud:
       config:
           enabled: false
           discovery:
               enabled: false
```

It didn't work.

What do I need to do to prevent the Rabbit components from starting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add spring-cloud-stream-test-support to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such an option like `disable` for Spring Cloud Stream.
As far as I know only the way to prevent Spring Cloud Stream to start in test environment is to exclude an appropriate Binder auto-configuration. In your case we talk about `RabbitServiceAutoConfiguration`:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ImportAutoConfiguration(exclude = RabbitServiceAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Comment: You can also set the [`autoStartup` consumer binding property](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_consumer_properties) to `false` to prevent the binder from starting.

Comment: Correct link [PropertiesRabbitMQ Consumer Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/rabbit/rabbit_overview/rabbitmq-consumer-properties.html)  I do not see any autostartup properties.  To get rid of the connection exceptions I started a rabbitmq test container.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
        BindingServiceConfiguration.class, FunctionConfiguration.class // spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit
    })
```