# Using TestChannelBinderConfiguration but two handlers get registered

Tags: spring, testing, spring-cloud-stream

I have a Spring Cloud Stream application that processes (credit card) events -- some of which are processed synchronously and some asynchronously. I came up with roughly the following in Kotlin:

spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit = 3.1.0

```
@Service
class CardEventProcessor(
    private val streamBridge: StreamBridge,
) : Consumer<AsyncCardEvent> {

    fun process(cardEvent: SyncCardEvent): Result { return businessLogic() }

    fun processAsynchronously(cardEvent: AsyncCardEvent) {
        streamBridge.send("cardEventProcessor-out-0", cardEvent)
    }

    override fun accept(cardEvent: AsyncCardEvent) { businessLogic() }
}
```

and have configured it like so:

```
  rabbitmq: ...
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        cardEventProcessor-in-0:
          destination: cardevents
          group: CardEventProcessor
        cardEventProcessor-out-0:
          destination: cardevents
```

It all seems to work fine, except in integration tests the processing fails after the *second* async card event. I was able to debug / reduce the issue down to two handlers being registered in `UnicastingDispatcher`, which has a round robin strategy: one for TestChannelBinder and another for OutputDestination$lamdba.

This is what my integration test class looks like:

```
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase
@Import(TestChannelBinderConfiguration::class)
class IntegrationTests {

    @Test
    fun `Use case one`() {
        sendFirstAsyncRequest()  // processed correctly in CardEventProcessor.accept()
        sendSecondAsyncRequest() // message never arrives in CardEventProcessor.accept()
    }
}
```

I was following the Testing section in Spring cloud stream docs and can't figure out what I'm missing to get this working. The example there is a Function<> not a Consumer<> and I produce within the same @Service class as the consumer (because the queue is just an implementation detail to solve async, not the typical use case of queues between micro-services) but as far as I understand that should work, and does in fact work when not running as integration test.

I saw [Disable Spring Cloud Stream Rabbit for tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59496895/disable-spring-cloud-stream-rabbit-for-tests) but didn't want to depend on the deprecated `spring-cloud-stream-test-support` and the other two suggestions didn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I see your `CardEventProcessor` does not fit the FunctionalInterface concept as it has two public methods to handle messages (possible resulting in two bindings), so I am suspecting it being related to your issue. The fact that it even works partially puzzles me a bit, so will investigate and follow up.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. CardEventProcessor implements Consumer<> and according to the docs "And in this context beans of type Supplier, Function or Consumer are treated as defacto message handlers...".  It is also the only such bean in the context, not sure if that influences the binding / wiring.

Maybe it's a separate question but the example in the docs shows `value.toUpperCase()` like functions with no external dependencies, and the old annotation based bindings are now marked as legacy. So whats a guy to do if the consumer e.g. needs to write to a database? How does that map to functional concept?

Comment: Sorry, i missed that, don't work with Kotlin all that often ;). So if it's a Consumer, only one binding will be created - input. That doesn't mean you can't use StreamBridge to send to `cardEventProcessor-out-0`, but that also mean that `cardEventProcessor-out-0` binding will be created dynamically. So the question why not just have CardEventProcessor  implement Function which would result in two bindings and you don't have to worry about manual send part as framework would take care of that?

Comment: Also, would it be possible for you to create a sample project with a bare minimum and the test you mentioned that reproduces the issue so we can look?

Comment: A Function won't work here because the chain is producer -> consumer, not consumer -> producer. There is no return value in consumer, the processed message gets written to DB so in essence the consumer is a void function -- hence consumer. The producer gets triggered by receiving a SOAP message over HTTP, not from an incoming queue. The reason process() is on CardEventProcessor is coherence: didn't want to bleed queue details into SOAP endpoint, it is implementation detail of CardEventProcessor.

Comment: Here is sample project to reproduce:
https://github.com/gnagy/test-channel-binder-triage

Comment: Raised an issue - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2106

Comment: I encountered the same problem while reactoring my code from StreamListener/Bindings to StreamBridge and functional style handlers. I spent around 8 hours to investigate the issue without any luck. A very ugly solution seems to be @DirtiesContext to ensure a clean application context for each test method, but this won't work for all scenarios and is slow...